# How to apply jQuery DatePicker in ASP.NET MVC in Create and Edit View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I have difficulty with applying jQuery DatePicker in Create and Edit view of particular controller that having one field say "PurchaseDate" with type DateTime. I have set all date format with Data Annotation. But still it is not working in Edit mode as expected.

Please reply if any have proper solution for same. Please refer below code:

I have one model class as below:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
```

And Edit view as below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, new { @class = "form-control date-picker", value = Model.PurchaseDate.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy") })
```

And I am applying jQuery DatePicker as below:

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({ rtl: App.isRTL(), autoclose: true });
```

Comment: Hello Devraj, please refer updated post for code snippet that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your jQuery code to

```
$('.form-control').datepicker({ rtl: App.isRTL(), autoclose: true });
```

Comment: Hello Rajesh,
CSS class is not having any problem I think, I have tried as you have suggested but still it creating problem in Edit view.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format in edit view does not match your model.

Your model has `DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"` and then you are formatting the value again in the edit view as `value = Model.PurchaseDate.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy")`.

Make both formats equal.

And give additional class to your text box as below.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, new { @class = "form-control date-picker", value = Model.PurchaseDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") })
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Devraj for kind help but still it is not working expected. Can you please suggest in brief about how to deal with jQuery DatePicker in ASP.NET MVC 4 application ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using MVC 5 but it should work in 4 nearly also: I have a Template-View:

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>    
@{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        DateTime dt = (System.DateTime)Model;
        @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", dt.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "datefield", type = "text" })   
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", string.Empty), new { @class = "datefield", type = "text" })    
    }            
}
```

which applies to all date fields ... is very important to make the type="text" this the only way it works with Chrome (with date Chrome leaves the field emty in edit)!!!

and then I have a JS file (forget the lang var if you need only english):

```
$(function () {
    var lang = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;       
    lang = lang.substring(0, 2);
    if (lang === "en")
        lang = "";
    $(".datefield").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
        minDate: "-6M", maxDate: "+1Y +6M +1D",
        showOn: "both", buttonImage: "/Content/themes/base/images/calendar22.gif", buttonImageOnly: true, buttonText: "Kalender",
    });
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[lang]);
  });
```

which is called/referenced in the _Layout.cshtml like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js")"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js")"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

at last you can call all this in your view where the datepicker should be with:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Enddate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Enddate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Enddate)
    </div>
</div>
```